# Is the following pointcut valid?

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

I came across the following Spring AOP pointcut in a tutorial:

```
execution(public * * (..))
```

it was said that it would cause the execution of all public methods. Is that correct? AFAIK we can only intercept public methods, and that public keyword there is even illegal.

Comment: pointcut: designator(return type, package.type.method(params))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @Mario's answer, the [spring docs on AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html) say the following (emphasis mine):

> Note Due to the proxy-based nature of Spring's AOP framework,
>   protected methods are by definition not intercepted, neither for JDK
>   proxies (where this isn't applicable) nor for CGLIB proxies (**where
>   this is technically possible but not recommendable for AOP purposes**).
>   As a consequence, any given pointcut will be matched against public
>   methods only!
>
> If your interception needs include protected/private methods or even
>   constructors, consider the use of Spring-driven native AspectJ weaving
>   instead of Spring's proxy-based AOP framework. This constitutes a
>   different mode of AOP usage with different characteristics, so be sure
>   to make yourself familiar with weaving first before making a decision.

In addition, the pointcut grammer is as follows:

```
execution(modifiers-pattern? ret-type-pattern declaring-type-pattern?
          name-pattern(param-pattern) throws-pattern?)
```

Wherby the `modifier-pattern` would be `public`,`protected` etc but is optional...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems to be a valid pointcut, and it does exactly what he says.

In addition, it is worth to note that replacing the "public" keyword with "protected" is perfectly legal and it still works! Strangely it works also with "private" methods...
(Tested with Spring 3.1.2 + AspectJ 1.6.9)

As far as I know, CGLib proxies can be used to proxy protected methods, however they are effective only if they are invoked from a different object instance. So technically, it should be possible to advice protected methods exactly in the same way as public ones.

(As reported by @beny23 advicing protected/private methods does not work with Spring AOP proxy implementation, but only with Spring driven AspectJ weaving)

Answer (score 0):

pointcut: `designator(modifier returnType package.type.method(params))`
in your case

```
execution(public * * (..))
```

would execute for all public methods with ANY return type in the project dir with 0 to many parameters